# Supress UserWarning from torchmetrics

Tags: python, pytorch, warnings

When I train a neural network using PyTorch, I get the following warning caused by the torchmetrics library:

> /Users/dev/miniconda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchmetrics/utilities/prints.py:36:
> UserWarning: Torchmetrics v0.9 introduced a new argument class
> property called `full_state_update` that has not been set for this
> class (SMAPE). The property determines if `update` by default needs
> access to the full metric state. If this is not the case, significant
> speedups can be achieved and we recommend setting this to `False`. We
> provide an checking function `from torchmetrics.utilities import check_forward_no_full_state` that can be used to check if the
> `full_state_update=True` (old and potential slower behaviour, default
> for now) or if `full_state_update=False` can be used safely.

I tried to suppress this warning by using the `warnings` package in my script:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

However, the warning is still shown which is probably due to a function in `prints.py` of torchmetrics:

```
def _warn(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    warnings.warn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is it possible to get rid of this warning from my script without changing the library code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-W` argument to control how `python` deals with warnings, consider following simple example, let `dowarn.py` content be

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("I am UserWarning", UserWarning)
warnings.warn("I am FutureWarning", FutureWarning)
```

then

```
python dowarn.py
```

gives

```
dowarn.py:2: UserWarning: I am UserWarning
  warnings.warn("I am UserWarning", UserWarning)
dowarn.py:3: FutureWarning: I am FutureWarning
  warnings.warn("I am FutureWarning", FutureWarning)
```

and

```
python -W ignore dowarn.py
```

gives empty output and

```
python -W ignore::UserWarning dowarn.py
```

gives

```
dowarn.py:3: FutureWarning: I am FutureWarning
  warnings.warn("I am FutureWarning", FutureWarning)
```

See `python` man page for discussion of `-W` values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have created a custom Metric class. If so, you may consider set `full_state_update` to True/False (default is None). Set it to True if you are not sure what you want.

```
class MyMetric(torchmetrics.Metric)
    full_state_update = None # set to False or True
```

This might be helpful: https://devblog.pytorchlightning.ai/torchmetrics-v0-9-faster-forward-d595bb321e6d